# Filter records submitted today in SQLite using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using two databases for different applications. In both applications I want to filter entries by **today** so I used the following function **in Postgres and it works wonderfully**.

```
    query = MyModel.query.filter(cast(MyModel.my_time_stamp, Date) == date.today()).all()
```

When I change the database to SQLite3, no results are shown. And the output of the query above in SQLite3 is:

```
>>> print(query) 
>>> []
```

**What I'm looking for is:**

Sorting records with timestamp, **in SQLite3**, and only show the records that have been entered today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just found and answer to my question:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from datetime import date

query = MyModel.query.filter(func.date(MyModel.my_time_stamp)==date.today()).all()
```

This would do the job.